# Embeded Google Doc Editor GWT when not logged in

Tags: java, gwt, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive in GWT based application. Basically I'm uploading files from my system to Google Drive and then based on the doc link I'm displaying uploaded document to edit it. I'm using Frame control to do this.
However, when I'm synchronized with Google Drive but I'm not logged in to my Google Account, document isn't displayed and I'm not asked to login to my Google Account. 
 When I paste URL into my browser I'm asked to login, as it should be. Is there any way to check if I'm logged in and ask user to do it otherwise?

Comment: I'm sure you can use it's own API to do so. I'm not familiar with google-drive-sdk but I think it is standard OAuth2.0 login.
On the GWT side you will have ask for permission then load the iframe. There here is the refference https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth

Comment: No its not about oauth2. Hes showing a google page in an iframe and for that there is no need for oauth. Not sure how you detect the logged-out situation but for sure you wont be able to iframe the google login page for security reasons (when you type your google password google wants you to see the window url starts with a google domain)

Comment: That make sense that Google won't display log in page in iframe, so the real question is how to detect if user is logged in or not ? It will be sufficient if I can simply inform user that he is not logged in